# How to update the plumber server smoothly?

Tags: docker, plumber

Recently I was using plumber to make API. But after deployed with docker, if I want to add some new api functions, the thing I have to do is to restart the docker. This makes the service not smooth. Is there any better way?

Comment: Not if you want to use plumber docker image as you cannot update the router without stopping it. And stopping it kills the docker container process.

Comment: @BrunoTremblay Got it, Thanks! But any solutions?

Comment: There are a lot a ways to deploy plumber. You could use digital ocean with the [plumberDeploy package](https://github.com/meztez/plumberDeploy). You could automate your deployment with github actions and some form of kubernetes. It really depends on the architecture you are trying to achieve. Could you provide more details so that it is possible to propose a working solution?